# Vagrant not running puppet

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I am running Vagrant and trying to configure the box with Puppet. Puppet never seems to run though. When I provision it, I see:

```
$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: notice: Finished catalog run in 0.03 seconds
```

My puppet file (in the default `manifests/default.pp`):

```
class base {
  Package { ensure => "installed" }
  package {
    "python-pip":
      ensure => "latest";
  }
}
```

My Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10" 
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true                          
  config.vm.provision "puppet"   # defaults to manifests/default.pp
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|                               
    vb.gui = false                                                      
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]                  
  end
end
```

When I try to run pip:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ pip
The program 'pip' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Why is pip not installing? Is the problem with my Vagrant file, my puppet file or my set up? Any ideas? I followed the Getting Started steps and this seems to be exactly what they have. I am running on Vagrant 1.6.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `manifests/default.pp` is just defining a class `base`, but it never actually declares it (via `include base`). It's the class declaration that causes it to "run".

From the [Puppet documentation on Classes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#defining-classes):

> Defining a class makes it available for later use. It doesn’t yet add any resources to the catalog; to do that, you must declare it (see below) or assign it from an ENC.

So, you should be able to get your `base` class to run by just calling `include base` later on in your `manifests/default.pp`.

Alternatively, in this simple scenario, you don't really even need a `base` class...you could just have a `manifests/default.pp` that says:

```
Package { ensure => "installed" }
package {
  "python-pip":
    ensure => "latest";
}
```